# Pincode Authentication Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible in Android to make use of the pin-code from the smartphone for authentication inside an application?

I've seen a lot of examples where the application makes use of a pincode but the pincode must always be configured inside the application. I wanna get the pincode that is been used to unlock the smartphone.

Comment: You probably can't get the pin code itself, but i think you can use Intent's with the lock screen app.. You request a check for administrative access, Lock screen appears, User enters PIN, Lock screen returns Successful Unlock or Failed Attempt...